# Serial Communication freezes with BMP180 and Arduino Mega

Tags: c++, arduino, sensors, i2c, serial-communication

I recently bought an ELEGO Mega 2560, or in other words an Arduino Mega. I bought a bmp180 sensor as well. I connected the bmp in this fashion, VCC - 3.3v, GND - GND, SCL - 21, SDA - 20. I uploaded a simple code which just displayes altitude. When I go to the Serial Monitor to view the results, nothing pops up. It is suppose to say BMP init success if it connects, and fail if it doesn't. When I go to the monitor, it just doens't say anything. When I disconnect the sensor, it says fail. It appears as if the Serial Monitor just freezes. Also a headsup, my code is very messy, I'm sorry if it's hard to keep up.

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SFE_BMP180.h>

SFE_BMP180 bmp180;
float Po = 1014.9;

#define ledPin 7
#define TransmitPin 5

//int Altitude = 5;

int sendValue;
String incomingString;

unsigned long lastTransmission;
const int interval = 1000;

void setup() {
  
  Wire.begin();
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(2, INPUT);
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(TransmitPin, OUTPUT);

  bool success = bmp180.begin();
  Serial.begin(115200);

  if (success) {
    Serial.println("BMP180 init success");
  }
  else 
    Serial.println("fail");
}

void loop() {
  sendValue = digitalRead(29);
  if (sendValue == HIGH) {
    if (millis() > lastTransmission + interval) {
      Serial.println("AT+SEND=1,8,Return");
      digitalWrite(TransmitPin, HIGH);
      delay(100);
      digitalWrite(TransmitPin, LOW);
      lastTransmission = millis();
    }
  }

  if (Serial.available()) {
    incomingString = Serial.readString();
    if (incomingString.indexOf("Testing!") > 0) {
      digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
      delay(100);
      digitalWrite(10, LOW);
    }
  }

  char status;
  double T, P, alt;
  bool success = false;

  status = bmp180.startTemperature();

  if (status != 0) {
    delay(1000);
    status = bmp180.getTemperature(T);

    if (status != 0) {
      status = bmp180.startPressure(3);

      if (status != 0) {
        delay(status);
        status = bmp180.getPressure(P, T);
        if (status != 0) {
          if (millis() > lastTransmission + interval) {
            alt = bmp180.altitude(P, Po);
            Serial.print("AT+SEND=1,8,");
            int altAsFoot = alt * 3.281;
            Serial.println(altAsFoot);
            digitalWrite(TransmitPin, HIGH);
            delay(100);
            digitalWrite(TransmitPin, LOW);
          }
          for (int i = 0; i < 1800; i++) {
            delay(1);
            if (Serial.available()) {
              incomingString = Serial.readString();
              if (incomingString.indexOf("+OK") > 0) {
                digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
                delay(100);
                digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
              }
              if (incomingString.indexOf("Testing!") > 0) {
                digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
                delay(100);
                digitalWrite(10, LOW);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not your problem with serial but your millis line is wrong.  Should use subtraction.  What you have will fail at rollover.

Comment: Tip: In C++ use `const int ledPin = 7;` instead of a typeless `#define`. Use whatever type you actually need.

Comment: Tip: If you're stuck on a problem and your code is "messy", that's a perfect time to clean things up. Often in the course of organizing things better you'll uncover something unexpected that may lead to solving the problem at hand.

Comment: Generally, cleaning up code will probably fix the issue. But this code works on an Arduino Nano, and it gets the job done there. So the issue has to be related to hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a hardware issue. I had ground shorted to SDA. I'm assuming the same will happen if it's shorted to SCL. Make sure both SDA and SCL aren't shorted to each other or ground.